# Casting a function pointer into a noexcept specified function pointer

Tags: c++, function-pointers, noexcept

Say I have these declarations:

```
using fp_type = void(*)();
using fp2_type = void(*)() noexcept;
```

and

```
void func(){}
fp_type fp(func);
```

Is the cast `fp2_type(fp)` well-formed? The other way around (casting a noexcept-specified function pointer into a function pointer without a noexcept specifier)?

Comment: "The other way around" is fine and actually an implicit conversion. `fp2_type(fp)` looks like it should be an `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: Interesting question. Note: *"15.4.12 An exception specification is not considered part of a function’s type"*

Comment: Actually, is this before or after they made exception specification part of the type system (i.e., is this for C++1z or C++14/earlier)?

Comment: I asked a very similar question about C++17 here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57596276/how-to-static-cast-throwing-function-pointer-to-noexcept-in-c17

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is ill-formed in C++14 and earlier:

```
using fp2_type = void(*)() noexcept;
```

due to N4140 [except.spec]/2:

> An *exception-specification* shall not appear in a typedef declaration or *alias-declaration*.

So I'm going to assume that the question is for C++1z, where exception specification is part of the type system.

---

[[conv.fctptr]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.fctptr):

> A prvalue of type “pointer to `noexcept` function” can be converted to
>   a prvalue of type “pointer to function”. The result is a pointer to
>   the function.

Thus, `void (*)() noexcept` can be (implicitly) converted to `void (*)()`.

[[expr.static.cast]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#7):

> The inverse of any standard conversion sequence (Clause [conv]) not
>   containing a [(various other cases omitted)] function pointer ([conv.fctptr]) conversion, can be performed
>   explicitly using `static_cast`.

Nothing else in [expr.static.cast] allows converting `void (*)()` to `void (*)() noexcept` either, so this is not a conversion that can be performed by a `static_cast`.

[[expr.reinterpret.cast]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#6):

> A function pointer can be explicitly converted to a function pointer
>   of a different type. The effect of calling a function through a
>   pointer to a function type ([dcl.fct]) that is not the same as the
>   type used in the definition of the function is undefined. Except that
>   converting a prvalue of type “pointer to `T1`” to the type “pointer to
>   `T2`” (where `T1` and `T2` are function types) and back to its original type
>   yields the original pointer value, the result of such a pointer
>   conversion is unspecified. [ Note: see also [conv.ptr] for more
>   details of pointer conversions.  — end note ]

So `reinterpret_cast` can perform this conversion.

Since `fp2_type(fp)` is equivalent to the C-style cast `(fp2_type) fp` ([[expr.type.conv]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.type.conv)), and [since C-style casts do a `reinterpret_cast` when `static_cast` is not possible](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cast#4) (ignoring `const_cast` for simplicity, as it's not relevant here), `fp2_type(fp)` is a well-formed `reinterpret_cast`. The result of such a cast cannot be used except to cast it back, however.

Comment: Related question, if you can convert a noexcept function to a regular one, can you do the same (or vice versa) with const and volatile member function pointers now?

Comment: There exists a workaround for the casting problem under c++11/14. Declare a function with the noexcept specifier, like void f() noexcept; then cast like decltype(&f)(fp). Maybe add this to your answer?