# How to static cast throwing function pointer to noexcept in C++17?

Tags: c++, c++17, function-pointers, static-cast, noexcept

C++17 makes `noexcept` part of a function's type. It also allows implicit conversions from `noexcept` function pointers to potentially throwing function pointers.

```
void (*ptr_to_noexcept)() noexcept = nullptr;
void (*ptr_to_throwing)() = ptr_to_noexcept;  // implicit conversion
```

http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#7 says that `static_cast` can perform the inverse of such a conversion.

```
void (*noexcept_again)() noexcept = static_cast<void(*)() noexcept>(ptr_to_throwing);
```

Unfortunately, both GCC and clang tell me otherwise: https://godbolt.org/z/TgrL7q

What is the correct way to do this? Are `reinterpret_cast` and C style cast my only options?

Comment: "reinterpret_cast and C style cast" <-- Those two are, more often than not, bugs. At least in *my* experience.

Comment: This question would be more useful if it discarded the confusion about `static_cast` and simply asked “How can I cast this?  What’s the danger?”.

Comment: I'm intentionally not asking what the danger is. This should be no more dangerous than a `const_cast` where the original object is declared non `const` or a base to derived cast where I know my base reference does in fact refer to a derived object. I'm only concerned that this `noexcept` cast *also* requires all the risk of `reinterpret_cast`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might have skipped over the important part:

> The inverse of any standard conversion sequence **not containing** an lvalue-to-rvalue, array-to-pointer, function-to-pointer, null pointer, null member pointer, boolean, **or function pointer conversion**, can be performed explicitly using static_­cast.

Currently, a function pointer conversion includes only the conversion from `noexcept` to potentially throwing. Because you're doing the inverse of a function pointer conversion, `static_cast` will not work, just like you can't `static_cast` a pointer to an array, or any of the other conversions listed there.

So yes, `reinterpret_cast` would be appropriate and also raises the appropriate alarm bells that should come with discarding `noexcept`.

Comment: Could you comment on why that restriction was added to `static_cast`?

Comment: @Filipp, I don't have anything more than speculation, but `static_cast` tends to stay away from more unsafe things and is usually there for when you need a value to be a different type. I picture `noexcept` similar to `const` in this regard where discarding it breaks a promise that was previously made, and this can have drastic consequences for the reader. Most of the other inverses don't make too much sense for C++. The one that has me confused is boolean conversions. Going from bool to a function pointer doesn't make much sense, but compilers allow bool to floating types in `static_cast`.